# Getting "originalRequire is not a function" when using benCoding AlarmManager in Titanium mobile project

Tags: android, notifications, titanium, alarmmanager, appcelerator

I am updating a Titanium mobile application which can schedule alarm notification for events, such that notification will pop up at the scheduled time.

Originally the mobile application is using a titanium module named as benCoding AlarmManager: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager to schedule notification. However after I upgraded titanium SDK from 8.3.0 to 9.0.0, I found that there would be error starting the application if I killed the application before the notification scheduled time. For example, if I schedule an alarm notification at 8:00 and the application is not running in the background at 8:00. Although notification will pop up at 8:00, there will be error when starting the application.

```
E/TiExceptionHandler: (main) [333,333] <embedded>:19295
      return originalRequire(moduleId);
             ^
    TypeError: originalRequire is not a function
        at global.require (<embedded>:19295:10)
        at <embedded>:19555:3
        at loadAsync (<embedded>:19481:5)
        at _startSnapshot (<embedded>:19552:1)
        at /ti.main.js:1:98
        at Module._runScript (ti:/module.js:587:9)
        at Module.load (ti:/module.js:106:7)
        at Function.Module.runModule (ti:/module.js:74:9)

        org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.nativeRunModule(Native Method)
        org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.doRunModule(V8Runtime.java:174)
        org.appcelerator.titanium.TiApplication.launch(TiApplication.java:791)
        org.appcelerator.titanium.TiLaunchActivity.loadScript(TiLaunchActivity.java:98)
        org.appcelerator.titanium.TiRootActivity.loadScript(TiRootActivity.java:480)
        org.appcelerator.titanium.TiLaunchActivity.onResume(TiLaunchActivity.java:179)
        org.appcelerator.titanium.TiRootActivity.onResume(TiRootActivity.java:499)
        android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1446)
        android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7939)
        android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4195)
```

I included one of my example code on AlarmManager, which will schedule a notification after pressing a button. The notification will be pop up after 2 minutes and pressing the notification will create error message "originalRequire is not a function".

```
// this sets the background color of the master UIView (when there are no windows/tab groups on it)
Ti.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');
// Add this in so Titanium will add the permission for us.
Titanium.Media.vibrate();
// Add this so Titanium will add the permissions and links needed to play sounds
var sound = Titanium.Media.createSound();

// Bring in the module
var alarmModule = require('bencoding.alarmmanager');
// Create a new instance of the Alarm Manager
var alarmManager = alarmModule.createAlarmManager();
// Create our basic window to put our example buttons on
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1', backgroundColor:'#fff', title:'Alarm Manager Tests'
});

var btn1 = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:"Alarm & Notify Basic", top:10, left:5, width: 150, height:75
});
win.add(btn1);
btn1.addEventListener('click', function(e){

    scheduleAlert = function(id, title, content) {
        id = parseInt(id);
        var date = new Date();
        alarmManager.cancelAlarmService(id);

        // To resolve the problem mutiple alarm at the same time using Android alarmanager
        var dateStr = "alarm" + date.getTime();

        Ti.API.info("addAlarmService:"+ date.getFullYear() + ", " + date.getMonth() + "," + date.getDate() + "," + date.getHours() + ","+date.getMinutes() + ", "+date.getSeconds());

        var hr = date.getHours();
        var min = date.getMinutes() + 2;
        var sec = date.getSeconds();

        alarmManager.addAlarmService({
            service : Ti.App.id + '.AlertServiceService',
            requestCode : id,
            //icon: Ti.Android.R.drawable.star_on, //Optional icon must be a resource id or url
            year : date.getFullYear(),
            month : date.getMonth(),
            day : date.getDate(),
            hour : hr,
            minute : min,
            second : sec
        });

        var ew = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title : 'Info', 
            message : "The Service provided will be started at " + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec,
            buttonNames : [Ti.Android.currentActivity.getString(Ti.Android.R.string.ok)]
        });
        ew.show();
    };  

    scheduleAlert(1, "Testing 123", "");

});

win.open();
```

I know that benCoding AlarmManager is a bit old and the last updated date is Jan 2018, however I do not know what alternatives can I use to generate notification same as AlarmManager in a Titanium application. Grateful if someone could provide advice for me on the error above or provide some alternatives on AlarmManager. Thanks.

Comment: are you using the normal module or one of the forks e.g. this one https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager/pull/92 Since the module was made for an older Android version may things have changed nativly to run things in background. On the other side the module is from the core SDK https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/e61e2035859a276d967c212185198fd3b8f6a3db/common/Resources/ti.internal/extensions/binding.js#L47 and this PR https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/11728 might be something to look at too. If the devices are online you could send a push

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using the fork one alarm manager module github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager/pull/92. The 11728 PR is very useful, but titanium SDK 9.1.0 is not released yet. Do I need to wait for titanium 9.1.0 and create a notification service in background to solve my problem? Or is there any way I can solve my problem in titanium 9.0.0?

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error as well on Ti SDK 9.0.2.GA but rather randomly and only when I schedule a notification from within a service after the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast event. If I schedule a notification from within the app, everything is fine.

Comment: In my case the cause was my Node version. After I downgraded from v12.X to v10.21.0 everything is working fine.